# Typescript decorators overriding property

Tags: typescript

I have the following decorator:

```
function Unique(target: any) {
    let original: any = target;

    let newConstructor: any = (...args: any[]) => {
        let obj = new original(args);
        Object.defineProperty(obj, 'unique', {
            value: true,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false
        });
        return obj;
    }

    newConstructor.prototype = original.prototype;

    return newConstructor;
}
```

and the following 2 classes:

```
@Unique
class Base {
    public get Name(): string { return 'Base'; }
    public irrelevantValue: number;

    public constructor() {
        this.irrelevantValue = 3;
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    public get Name(): string { return 'Child'; }
    public otherIrrelevantValue: number;

    public constructor() {
        super();

        this.otherIrrelevantValue = 9;
    }
}
```

However, when I do

```
let obj = new Child();
console.log(obj.Name);
```

I get `Base` not `Child`. This is only the case when the Unique decorator is present, so I believe the issue is with the way Unique is overwriting the target's prototype.

How can I use a constructor override decorator on a parent class without overriding inherited properties/values/methods?

It's worth noting that with the above example, calling `obj.otherIrrelevantValue` will correctly return 9.

Comment: Why do you use `super.otherIrrelevantValue` (not `this`) in `Child` constructor? Is this on purpose?

Comment: @Cerberus my bad, typo in the question, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return an object from the constructor that object will become the instance returned by `new`. Since you use `new` to call the base constructor, this will create a new instance of the base class (not the current class being created) and this instance of base will become the return value of `new Child`

The safest way to do this, replace the original class by extending it, is to use standard class extension syntax:

```
function Unique<T extends new (...arg: any[])=> any>(target: T) {
    let original: any = target;

    return class extends target {
        constructor(...args: any[]){
            super(...args);
            Object.defineProperty(this, 'unique', {
                value: true,
                configurable: false,
                writable: false
            });
        }
    };
}

@Unique
class Base {
    public get Name(): string { return 'Base'; }
    public irrelevantValue: number;

    public constructor() {
        this.irrelevantValue = 3;
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    public get Name(): string { return 'Child'; }
    public otherIrrelevantValue!: number;

    public constructor() {
        super();

        this.otherIrrelevantValue = 9;
    }
}

let obj = new Child();
console.log(obj.Name);
```

Or using your original syntax:

```
function Unique<T extends new (...arg: any[])=> any>(target: T) {

    let newConstructor: any = function (this: any, ...args: any[])  {
        let _this =  target.apply(args) || this; // replce this only if the base calss retunrs somthing (It usually will not)
        Object.defineProperty(_this, 'unique', {
            value: true,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false
        });
        return _this;
    }

    newConstructor.prototype = target.prototype;
    return newConstructor;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, so we essentially encapsulate the constructor we wish to return in an anonymous object that extends the target? That makes sense, I'll try it now and see if it resolves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: So the "using your original syntax" example did not work, it seems as though the prototype didn't copy across properly, as the resulting object was missing most members from both Base and Child. However the standard class extension method works perfectly, so I'll be using that going forward. I also think it looks cleaner than my code.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Mayube wierd .. I tested again to make sure and it works for me ..anyway, the class way is nicer :)

Comment: It was possibly just an implementation detail between the MRE I provided in the question and the codebase I'm actually working with. But yes, the class way looks so much cleaner, I've just refactored all of our Decorators to use that method and everything is working smoothly.